# number range for select values with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

I have this select with simple_form:

```
<%= f.input :theme, :collection => ["#{t('.text_1')}", "#{t('.text_2')}", "#{t('.text_3')}", "#{t('.text_4')}", :value_method => lambda { |n| n } %>
```

The html is:

```
<select class="select required" id="inquiry_theme" name="inquiry[theme]"><option value="">Choose a topic related to your query</option>
<option value="Text1">Text1</option>
<option value="Text2">Text2</option>
<option value="Text3">Text3</option>
<option value="Text4">Text4</option>
```

I want set the value with a range numbers instead text e.g.:

```
<select class="select required" id="inquiry_theme" name="inquiry[theme]"><option value="">Choose a topic related to your query</option>
<option value="1">Text1</option>
<option value="2">Text2</option>
<option value="3">Text3</option>
<option value="4">Text4</option>
```

**Is possible with a lambda in `:value_method`?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your example, I think using `value_method` is a little overkill.

```
<%= f.input :theme, :collection => [[1, "#{t('.text_1')}"], [2, "#{t('.text_2')}"], [3, "#{t('.text_3')}"], [4, "#{t('.text_4')}"]] %>
```

Though I'd write this as

```
<%= f.input :theme, :collection: (1..4).map { |i| [i, t(".text_#{i}")] }.unshift([nil, 'Choose a topic related to your query'] %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example output , I write like this it may be useful for you.

```
<%= f.select :theme,options_for_select((1..4).to_a.map{|x| [x,"Text#{x}"]}.insert(0, "Choose a topic related to your query")) ,:id=>"inquiry_theme" %>
```